# AngularJS typeahead add entry to result list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead

I have a typeahead that works ok, but I want the ability to add a text to the result list in case the text does not match any existing words, and I want this option to appear immediately.

This works ok here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Gy37Qo6DDusou2GaWMWv?p=preview

However, in the case where the asynchronous takes some time to return the result list is empty while waiting. I would like to run this line,

script.js:15: 
`addresses.push({formatted_address: val+" (new)", geometry: "custom"});`

before the asynchronous request returns.

To demonstrate how this does not work, I change the address in the request, "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json",
to something invalid. In that case the typeahead will not show anything, even though I would like to see the written text as a suggestion.

I hope this was understandable!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by putting the `addresses` variable on `$scope`, and then reading from it in the typeahead, instead of from the `getLocation` method. You will need to update this on changes to the input, so add an `ng-change` attribute on the input and call your `getLocation` method from there, and in the ajax query callback, just append the results to the addresses array.

```
<input 
    id="input"
    type="text" 
    ng-model="asyncSelected" 
    ng-change="getLocation()"
    placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" 
    typeahead="address as address.formatted_address for address in addresses" 
    typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" 
    class="form-control">
```

(Note: ngChange has some problems in solving this, so I'd recommend you to create a custom directive that has somewhat modified behaviour). See a rudimentary solution here: http://plnkr.co/edit/dfb6PMLpFj6euFye4C8z?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work. I tried something similar before, but ended up with the same problem. As you can see in your example the typeahead get one character behind. When I write "a" i get an empty result, when i write "ab" I get a result for "a" etc.